# Google Aps Script - Trigger function when Column is "START"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need function to simply trigger another function if a specific Google Sheet column's value (or values) is "START".

Something like this:
If column AUTO!N2:N is "START", then trigger the function letsStart()"
If column AUTO!N2:N is not "START", then do nothing.

Simple as that :)

Is this possible?

The letsStart() function already **ends** with:

```
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AUTO")

  .getRange('N2:N')
  .createTextFinder('START')
  .replaceAllWith('STOP')
```

...and working fine.

This is to avoid unintended looping.

Comment: Do cells get the value `START` via script or via the user manually editing the sheet? If it's the latter, a simple `onEdit` trigger would be enough for this. In case it's the former, I'd suggest using a time-driven trigger for this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to run a function of `letsStart()` when the cells `AUTO!N2:N` includes a value of "START".

In this case, how about the following 2 patterns?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, when a cell in `AUTO!N2:N` is edited and the cell value is "START", `letsStart()` is run.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const { range, source } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const value = range.getValue();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "AUTO" || range.columnStart != 14 || range.rowStart == 1 || value != "START") return;
  letsStart();
  // or range.setValue("STOP");
}
```

- In this sample, a simple trigger of OnEdit is used. So, when you use this script, please edit a cell of `AUTO!N2:N`. By this, the script is run. When you put "START" to `AUTO!N2:N`, `letsStart()` is run.

  - Please be careful about this.
- In this case, I thought that `range.setValue("STOP");` might be able to be also used instead of `letsStart();`.

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, when the cells `AUTO!N2:N` includes a value of "START", `letsStart()` is run.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AUTO");
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  if (lastRow == 0) return;
  const textFinder = sheet.getRange("N2:N" + lastRow).createTextFinder("START").matchEntireCell(true);

  if (!textFinder.findNext()) return;
  letsStart();
  // or textFinder.replaceAllWith("STOP");
}
```

- When this script is run, when the cells `AUTO!N2:N` includes a value of "START", `letsStart()` is run. Althought I'm not sure your whole script of `letsStart()`, when I saw your script of `letsStart()`, I thoug that in this case, I thought that `letsStart();` might be able to be replaced with `textFinder.replaceAllWith("STOP");`.
- For example, when `myFunction` is modified to `onEdit`, this script can be also used with the simple trigger of OnEdit.

#### References:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: Seems like the Pattern 2 worked out best. I will test it a bit more and give feedback...

Comment: Been testing Pattern 2 for a few days and it works great. No errors. Thanks.

Comment: @The Denster First, I apologize for my late reply. About `Been testing Pattern 2 for a few days and it works great. No errors. Thanks.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer